# What is this Error (Network-related) in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linq

Please Help Me 
I'm Work on a C# program with a Local Database with linq and SomeTimes if i want to open my database this Error Show and i must Repair Visual Studio To Error stay away
How Can i Repair it ?

[image]

This is My Connection String

```
> <configuration>
>     <configSections>
>         <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
>             <section name="Shop.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
> allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="true" />
>         </sectionGroup>
>     </configSections>
>     <connectionStrings>
>         <add name="Shop.Properties.Settings.LocalConnectionString"
>             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Local.mdf;Integrated
> Security=True;User Instance=True"
>             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
>     </connectionStrings>
>     <userSettings>
>         <Shop.Properties.Settings>
>             <setting name="Hamid" serializeAs="String">
>                 <value>Shop</value>
>             </setting>
>         </Shop.Properties.Settings>
>     </userSettings> </configuration>
```

Comment: The problem seems related with SQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

check your connection string .. it says your program is not able to access the SQL server

Comment: Please CheCk my Connection string in my first Post

Comment: i think connection string is right please check you sql express is runing or not

Comment: Do you have a Link to  Download Sql Express ??

Comment: It seems that you have no clue about what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that SQL server might not be running. Will you check if your server is running or not. Above error occurs mostly when , either Server is not running or the server does not exist (wrong connection string) . From checking your connection string , it seems like it is pointing to local host. 
you are sure that you have SQL installed on your machine, right ?

Regards.

Comment: You Can Check My connection string On My firs Post !! my Database is in Directory File with Local.mdf name

Comment: I told you that connection string seems right. Can you check the other things I mentioned , like if sqlexpress is running or not. You can check that in your task manager->services. you should see SQLSERVER or SQLEXPRESS . it should be in running/started state.